# need help converting time string to usable format

Tags: php

I have a string in the following format
    yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss

The reason its in this format is because its part of a URL. I need help converting it to a usable time format in PHP.

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
$time = "2013-04-14-23-33-17";
$time2 = strtotime($time);
$time3 = date('M d, Y', $time2) . ' ' . _('at') . ' ' . date('h:i a', $time2);
echo $time3;
```

It just echos out Jan 01, 1970 at 12:00 am which is wrong instead of Apr 14, 2013 at 11:33 pm.

Comment: January 1, 1970 midnight was the unix epoch. Essentially, you are returned `false` when you parse the string. The `false` is then converted to `0` which is then parsed as a seconds offset by PHP.

Comment: It is part of the "Main" script for translation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to help you with the parsing:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d-H-i-s', $time);
echo $date->format('M d, Y h:i a');
```

Comment: Awesome, I was unaware of this PHP function. Thanks!

Comment: @JesseWilliamSzypulski It's relatively new, introduced in 5.3.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because that's not a valid date format. See [Supported Date and Time Formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).

What you need to do is create a DateTime object by specifing a format for your string.

[`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) does exactly that.